# Searching for [foo][bar] redirects to [foobar]

Tags: bug, status-completed, tags, search, hyperlinks

If you type [`[foo][bar]`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfoo%5D%5Bbar%5D) into the search box, it redirects to a list of questions tagged [`[foobar]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/foo%5d%5bbar). Insterting [a space](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfoo%5D+%5Bbar%5D) works properly, but both versions used to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a bug (and/or lack of a feature) in the new parsing of search queries.  It will be fixed in the next build sometime tonight.